# AngularJs - temporary injection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created this sample ([**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/EPabuQAm/4/edit)) which shows a band member and an instrument he plays with.

This is how it looks :

[image]

At first , no one plays at anything , and so the `instumentId` is null :

```
s.users= [
        { id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Lennon', instrumentId: null },
        { id: 2, firstname: 'Paul', lastname: 'McCartney', instrumentId: null},
        { id: 3, firstname: 'George', lastname: 'Harrison', instrumentId: null },
        { id: 4, firstname: 'Ringo', lastname: 'Star', instrumentId: null },
    ];
```

When I click "edit" - I have a template which is in :

[image]

And the user should choose  :

[image]

All ok.

But I have 2 problems :

**Question 1 :**

Currently the template is in each row ( hidden) and I dont want that ! I want it to be temporary injected ( so user will be able to choose an instrument ) and then remove it from dom.

How can I do it ?

**Question 2 :**

The template is :

```
 <script type=text/ng-template id='instrument.html'>
    <select ng-model='instrumentDdl' >
     <option ng-repeat='ins in instruments'>{{ins.id +' - '+ins.name}}</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

So I bind the `select` to `ng-model='instrumentDdl'` . Also , the `save` function do this :

```
  s.save=function (user){ 
    console.log(s.instrumentDdl) //<----- undefined...why ?
    user.instrumentId=s.instrumentDdl;
   s.userUnderEdit  = null;
  };
```

But I get `undefined`  at the `console.log(s.instrumentDdl)` ( `s===$scope`). why is that ?

---

**PS , My goal** : dynamic temporary injection , and when saved - to look like (john's only example):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

I removed the `ngInit` as it's not what you need.
Here is a working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/EPabuQAm/11/edit

Inside  the template use `ngOptions` & `ngModel`:

```
<script type=text/ng-template id='instrument.html'>
    <select ng-model='user.instrumentSelected' 
            ng-options="(ins.id + ' - ' + ins.name) for ins in instruments">    
</script>
```

Users list , use `ngIf`:

```
<li ng-repeat='user in users'>
    {{user.firstname +' '+  user.lastname + ' plays at: '+ (user.instrumentDdl.name ||'?')  }}

    <button ng-click='edit(user)'>Edit</button>
    <div  ng-if='user.isEdited'> Tool : 
        <my-tool > </my-tool>
        <button ng-click='save(user)'>Save</button> 
        <button ng-click='cancel(user)'>Cancel</button>           
     </div>
 </li>
```

**Contoller:** - set the variable on save, edit & cancel events

```
scope.edit=function (user){ 
    user.isEdited = true;
};

scope.cancel = function (user)
{
    user.isEdited=false;
};

scope.save=function (user){ 
    user.isEdited=false;
    user.instrumentDdl= user.instrumentSelected;
};
```

You can also get a way without any scope functions:

```
 <button ng-click='user.isEdited = true'>Edit</button>
 <div  ng-if='user.isEdited'> Tool : 
    <my-tool > </my-tool>
    <button ng-click='user.isEdited = false; user.instrumentDdl = user.instrumentSelected'>Save</button> 
    <button ng-click='user.isEdited = false'>Cancel</button>           
 </div>
```

Comment: tnx. why the template is open and present at each row ?

Comment: What do you mean by why? `ng-init` initiates `user.isEdited = true`

Comment: my first question is talking about it. I dont want to duplicate this template in the dom. I want it to appear only at the edited row. (I dont want even hidden) the template should be injected only at the relevant row and disposed after save/cancel.

Comment: Also  , why did you put in the template :`ng-model='user.instrumentSelected'` ? this will bind to `$scope.user.instrumentSelected` ....right ?

Comment: yes, `ngRepeat` creates a new child scope for each item so it's scoped to the right item

Answer (score 2):

For Question 1 use `ng-if='user.isEdited'`

For Question 2 try with select and `ng-option`

**Update**: My bad on the question 2. You need to provide some of your directive code and where are you calling `s.save` (html element) to know why is it not working.

**Update 2**: Looking at your jsbin, this is a scoping issue.

`<li ng-repeat='user in users'>` is creating a new scope for each user. `instrumentDdl` is getting added to the scope created for each user when you show the dropdown. It is not getting added to the parent controller scope. You can do is write

`<button ng-click='save(user,instrumentDdl)'>Save</button>`

and the change the save method accordingly.

Comment: Do I deserve such a poor answer for this very detailed question ? ( Also , `ng-option` is not related. my sample also works. you can use also `ng-repeat`. Also , I dont see how ng-if related to dynamic _temporary_ insertion. Also ,  a fiddle would be much appreciated.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, well i have fixed some part of the answer.

Comment: console.log(s.instrumentDdl)  this smell a little I think should be instrumentDdl all in all it's the model

Comment: ng-if only injects html in DOM when the condition is true.

Comment: @Whisher no. it appended tpo the $scope object. and the $scope is `s` in my code.

Comment: @Chandermani can you please supply fiddle ? Edit. I succeed with  the first stage with `ng-if` ( **tnx**). what about the second stage ?

Comment: @Chandermani After edit-  I agree. that's why I rolled back :-)

Comment: @Chandermani  Can u **please supply fiddle** so other will learn too please

Comment: Here is basically a demo of this idea http://plnkr.co/edit/q41vhF61htoGdIVToIqn?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq thanks for the plunker , however there is a DDL for each row in the repeater. I wanted it to be inserted .not hidden.